# How to determine bitwise binary scores for a list of number in perl?

Tags: perl, binary

I am trying to inter-convert some decimal and binary numbers. I am working with data produced in the following format:

```
Example decimal: 163,   Corresponding binary: 10100011

Binary table key:
```

[image]

```
...and the corresponding description for the binary number in question:
```

[image]

I want to be able to take a decimal number, convert it to binary, and then use this look-up table to print a list of attributes for a given decimal. I'm able to convert my decimal to binary using this code:

```
sub dec2bin {
    my $str = unpack("B32", pack("N", shift));
    $str =~ s/^0+(?=\d)//;   # otherwise you'll get leading zeros
    return $str;
}
```

But then don't see how to use the lookup table. The problem is, I have binary numbers specifically designed to be compatible for this table, such as 1000011, 10000011, 101110011, but I just don't see how to use these binaries to pull our their descriptions. They are even different lengths!

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here?

EDIT:   here is another look-up table I found... perhaps this is more accurate/helpful? It looks identical to me, but is from the software's offiical [website](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/samtools.shtml#5).

[image]

Comment: Did you mistype the binary number? Looks like it should be `11000011` from your tabular description.

Comment: I thought so too! But this isn't a typo... this is from the official description website for samtools, which is a very prominent set of software tools for biologists, and other guides I've found use similar examples.

Comment: That is confusing then because `0x20` maps to 32 (base 10) and the 32 bit is set in the number above, but the table does list the `0x20` description. It lists the `0x80` (64, base 10) description.

Comment: I added the official look-up table from the website and a link to the site as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the number is converted, its base as expressed in the input is irrelevant. Internally, think of it as just a number.

The value 163 expresses a *bitfield*, that is, each of its bits is the answer to some yes-no question, and the table tells you how the questions are arranged.

You might give the bits human-readable names with subs, as in

```
sub read_is_paired { $_[0] & 0x0001 }
sub read_is_mapped { $_[0] & 0x0002 }
sub strand_of_mate { $_[0] & 0x0020 }
sub read_is_2nd    { $_[0] & 0x0080 }
```

Then decoding the bitfield resembles

```
my $flags = 163;
print "read is paired?  ", read_is_paired($flags) ? "YES" : "NO", "\n",
      "read is mapped?  ", read_is_mapped($flags) ? "YES" : "NO", "\n",
      "strand of mate = ", strand_of_mate($flags) ? "1"   : "0",  "\n",
      "read is second?  ", read_is_2nd($flags)    ? "YES" : "NO", "\n";
```

Output:

```
read is paired?  YES
read is mapped?  YES
strand of mate = 1
read is second?  YES
```

Comment: Thanks for the conceptual and coding solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Any easier method might just be to examine each key in your map and compare it directly to your converted number.

```
sub get_descriptions {
   my $binary_num = shift;
   my @descriptions; 

   for my $k (keys %description_map) {
      # bitwise comparison
      if( $k & $binary_num ) {
         # add description because this bit is set
         push @descriptions, $description_map{$k};
      }
   }

   # full listing of all descriptions for the set bits
   return @descriptions; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is in base 16, so simply convert to base 2 (I copied/pasted the table from another forum, please fix if it's different from your screenshots):

```
0000000001 the read is paired in sequencing
0000000010 the read is mapped in a proper pair
0000000100 the query sequence itself is unmapped
0000001000 the mate is unmapped
0000010000 strand of the query (1 for reverse)
0000100000 strand of the mate
0001000000 the read is the first read in a pair
0010000000 the read is the second read in a pair
```

etc...

To get the correcy description in your format would then be the following code:

```
my @descriptions = ( 
   "the read is paired in sequencing"
  ,"the read is mapped in a proper pair"
  #...
);
check_number(163); # Note that you don't need to convert to binary :)

sub check_number {
    my $number = shift;
    my $bitmask = 1; # will keep incrementing it by *2 every time
    for($i=0; $i < @descriptions; $i++) {
        my $match = $bitmask & $number ? 1 : 0; # is the bit flipped on?
        print "|$match| $descriptions[$i] | \n";
        $bitmask *= 2; # or bit-shift - faster but less readable.
    }
}
```

The output from my test code was (Sorry, got lazy copy/pasting description strings so faked them):

```
$ perl5.8 17152880.pl
|1| the read is paired in sequencing |
|1| the read is mapped in a proper pair |
|0| 3 |
|0| 4 |
|0| 5 |
|1| 6 |
|0| 7 |
|1| 8 |
|0| 9 |
```

If you ONLY want to print descriptions that match, change the print statement in the loop to   `print "$descriptions[$i]\n" if $match;`

The benefit of this approach is that it's easily extended to longer description table

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I chose the other answer because the code made a little more sense to me, but your answer was very helpful as well!

Comment: @jake9115 - the accepted answer is a little less extensible, but you are the OP so you get to decide which one is more helpful :)

Comment: @DVK By `$number` you mean a parameter to your function right ? Also, I thought my solution was very clean.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - that's what happens when you refactor in SO instead of decent editor :) Fixed, thx